# Unity Game Engine Crashing When Trying To Update The Vertex Positions Of A Mesh In Real Time Using A Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, monodevelop, mesh

So in unity I’ve created a script which successfully generates a plane mesh made up of triangles. The plane is has 400 vertices (20x20 grid) with 361 squares made up of 2 triangles comprising 3 vertices each (2166 indices). As was mentioned the vertices, indices and normals are set in the start() function with the vertices being loaded into a vector3 array called vertices, the indices being loaded into an array of single floats and the normals being loaded into an array of vector3. These are then assigned to a mesh (representing the plane) int the Start() function like so:

```
    mesh.vertices = vertices;
    mesh.triangles = triangles;
    mesh.normals = normals;
```

In the update() function a function is called which calculates new positions for every single vertex in the plane mesh (400):

```
void Update () 
{
    updateMesh ();
    mesh.vertices = vertices;
}
```

With the updateMesh function looking like this:

```
void updateMesh()                                                                       
{                                                                                           
    //This function will update the position of each vertex in the mesh

    for (float i = 0f; i<1f; i=+0.05f) {
        for (float j = 0f; j<1f; j+=0.05f) {
            pos = (int)((i * 20) + (j*20));
            vertices[pos] = updatePt(j, i);

        }
    }
}
```

Once the new vertices have been updated, the indices and normals remain the same but the newly calculated vertex positions must be loaded onto the mesh object. And this is also attempted in the Update() function as can be seen above.

However as soon as the play button is pressed in unity, the engine crashes and I’m not sure why – is it possible the recalculation function is not finishing its cycle before unity renders? (I have already reduced the number of vertices in the mesh because the same problem was occurring when the mesh had 10000 vertices (100x100 grid)). Or is it because I am not doing something properly in the Update() function?

Comment: What does the editor log say? You can find it here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html

Comment: Does it still crash if you comment out the call to `updateMesh()` method?

Comment: Have you tried using the `UploadMeshData()` method? http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.UploadMeshData.html

Comment: @golergka - the engine does not crash if the updateMesh() function is commented out - it renders the plane mesh as normal (without the updates obviously). I have not tried the UploadMeshData() function so thanks for pointing it out to me.

Comment: Just tried calling the UploadMeshData() function in the update function like so: mesh.UploadMeshData(true); in the Update() function and Unity is still crashing, worth a shot though ><

Comment: What if you just run the `updateMesh` method without uploading the mesh data? What if you run it on data completely unrelated to mesh vertices, just abstract arrays of stuff? In general, it is a good practice to localize the bug as much as possible, and remove everything that you can reproduce the bug without.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it might be the typo at the line

```
for (float i = 0f; i<1f; i=+0.05f) {
```

It should read += not =+ .

It is probably getting stuck in an infinite loop because i is never incremented.

Comment: That did it - was stuck in an infinite loop as you say - the engine no longer crashes when the updateMesh() function is called in the Update() function.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to point out that it would be much better to use integers to iterate over the effectively 2D array and calculate the final array index wholly using integer math. E.g.

If you rely on floating point maths, you may generate indices like 19.99. This would then be rounded to index the array. Not ideal! Hope this helps.

```
    static int meshWidth = 20;
    static int meshHeight = 20;

    void updateMesh()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i< meshHeight; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < meshWidth; j++)
            {
                int pos = i * meshWidth + j;

                // Also change updatePt func to receive two ints...
                vertices[pos] = updatePt(j, i); 
            }
        }
    }
```